# Add paperclip url to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Normally in html we will use Model.field.url(:thumb) inside image tag, How to do it on json, especially with hash_secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model add the following to get the url (I believe this also works with hashing):

```
def photo_url_thumb
    photo.url(:thumb)
end
```

And then you can output json like this:

```
 format.json { render :json => @model.photo_url_thumb }
```

Answer (score 6):

In case of this being helpful to anyone, i find out a nice way to do this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "500x500#", :medium => "300x300#", :small => "100x100#", :thumb => "50x50#" }

  def as_json(options)
    json = super
    self.avatar.styles.each do | format |
      json = json.merge({"avatar_"+format[0].to_s => self.avatar(format[0])})
    end
    json
  end
end
```

You can then simply call

```
render :json => @my_model
```

Also working while rendering collections.

It is then possible to do some conditional rendering with as_json(options), with something like:

```
model_to_json = @my_model.to_json(:nested => true)
render :json => model_json
```