# Adding paperclip URL to JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip, rails-activerecord

Please reference this question: [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588185/how-can-i-get-url-for-paperclip-image-in-to-json) or [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650959/add-paperclip-url-to-json)

I cannot seem to get my `work` scaffold to include the image URL from paperclip to JSON.  I need this url to do some ajax manipulation to the dom.

To my understanding you add a def in a model and then you add a extra line to the format.json in the controller.

when I add the @work.avatar_url to my controller method `def create` it throws up a syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
```

I'm really new to rails and MVC.  All the answers make it sound so easy.  Unfortunately, I'm just guessing and checking...

### Controller Link: **[works_controller.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/controllers/works_controller.rb)**

My Def Create

```
def create
    @work = Work.new(params[:work])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @work.save
        format.html { redirect_to @work, notice: 'Work was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @work, status: :created, location: @work }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @work.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

### Git Link Model: **[work.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/models/work.rb)**

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many  :categoryworks
  has_many :categories, :through => :categoryworks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
  attr_accessible :name, :subtitle, :category_ids, :svg, :post_a, :post_b, :post_c, :post_d, :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "1280x700>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

   def avatar_url
     avatar.url(:medium)
   end

end
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
format.json { render json: @work.as_json(:methods => [:avatar_url]), status: :created, location: @work }
```

instead of what you have used.

Comment: Still nothing :c i put this in my create definition ? yeah?

Comment: Could you please show the response after adding this to the controller?