# how do you get paperclip url to json in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, paperclip

I'm aware of the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650959/add-paperclip-url-to-json) pertaining to this subject, but none seem to help. I want the paperclip image url passed to json so I can render it in a reactjs component. I obviously cannot use Rails' [image_tag](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers) helper.

I've defined this method in my items model

```
def image_url
  image.url(:thumb)
end
```

And this in my controller

```
def index
  @items = Item.all   
  render :json => @items.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])
end
```

But literally all that does is replace the rendered page with json. How should I go about this? It doesn't make sense to create a migration and model validation specifically for the image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to format the html.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @items.to_json(:methods => [:image_url]) }
end
```

Still doesn't solve the part where I'm trying to use that method in a reactjs component, but that's another issue.